# Did i get scammed?

Tags: fraud

So last week, when i was walking in a supermarket, a guy approached me and ask if i can withdraw $200 of cash for him because his card doesnt work. So I got his detail and withdraw 200$ for him and he transfer the money to me online. I did manage to get his name and phone number. But after few hours i still dont receive the money from him so i texted him and he say he will get the cash and give it to me the next day. But the next day he made an excuse and did not appear. Then this happen again for the next day. What can i do? This guy is from the same university as me but i dont have his address. He seems to reply and and dont reply and unwilling to give me his address in order to get the money from him. This happens in England. Can i report to the polis? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well normally a scam is more creative and manipulative than this. It sounds like you basically got asked "hey I really need $200 dollars right now" and presumably because you wanted to be helpful, you decided to help, but the other party took advantage of you. You got taken advantage of, not scammed. It doesn't seem like fraud either because he actually literally just asked you for $200 and you decided to give it to him.

Answer (score 1):

> Did i get scammed?

Maybe but its not entirely clear that you are the victim of [fraud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraud). For fraud to occur, the perpetrator must have intended to deprive you of your money at the time they asked for it and we have no evidence of such an intent.

Legally, it appears that you have an agreement (possibly a contract) that you would lend the person $200 (if you are in England, why this isn't pounds rather than dollars I can't imagine) and they would repay you the next day. What you have is a delinquent debt that is proving difficult to collect. Not paying your debts is not a crime, so it is of no interest to the police.

All you can really do is keep chasing the person down and asking for your money. You could sue them but the costs of doing so will be far greater than the amount concerned.

Worst case, $200 is relatively cheap for a valuable life lesson - don't lend money to strangers.

> Neither a Borrower Nor a Lender Be

Polonius, Act 1, Scene 3, Hamlet

Comment: Someone asked for money than won't meet with him to return it. He was stolen from. Again, you are misusing legal terms, by trying to fit a certain situation into a term rather than going by the situation.

Comment: @Putvi no, if you stop paying your bank loan, you have not committed a crime. The police will not be interested.

Comment: the police won't get involved, because the bank has a formal contract and you can go to civil court. If you just flee and never pay the loan back the police will get involved and you will end up in prison. There's plenty of TV shows showing people going to jail for mortgage schemes.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you did get scammed and yes call the police. Don't tell him you are calling the police though.

Comment: OP willingly gave a stranger $200 without any apparent coercion. As for a crime, not sure what it'd be (I assume there's no written and signed promise to repay OP).  ...At the very least this is a $200 lesson to be more guarded in such situations. But it may be worth contacting police, I'd bet this guy does this regularly in the same general area so perhaps they can move him off premises or something to that effect.

Comment: If the person never had any intention to repay but said that he would repay, then it is fraud.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite It's theft tbh.